# In VB what is meant when a line of code is placed between <>

Tags: vb.net

what is meant by the <> in this code?

```
    <System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version:="1.0", Publisher:="", Description:="")> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is *attributes* ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx)).

It is permissible for them to be placed on the same line as type or member declaration (as is the case with the `CLSCompliantAttribute` in your example).

Comment: So its like extending the capabilities of a class or object with attributes that wouldn't be normally associated with that object type??

Comment: @Craigoh1, correct. Attributes are annotations which provide additional metadata on programming elements (types and members) that they decorate. This metadata can be useful in a number of scenarios: serialization, interop etc. Entity Framework Data Annotations is a good example of a use case for custom attributes.